# Android Instrumentation testing an AsyncTask

Tags: android, instrumentation

I am new to instrumentation testing in Android. Can someone show me how i can start an async task and wait for the result to be computed ? Many of my network calls rely on AsynTasks and i need to know how we can test it ? For activities we have a getInstrumentation().waitForMonitor , what can we do for AsyncTasks ?

Answer (score 1):

The `AsyncTask` class has a blocking [`get()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#get%28%29) method that will basically wait for the task to finish before it returns. It's the synchronous version of calling `execute()`, which means you could think of it as the background work being executed on the main thread - hence it blocks until finished.

```
public final Result get ()
```

> Waits if necessary for the computation to complete, and then retrieves
>   its result.